# Installing Windows 7 on ThinkPad X200

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

What is the right way to install Windows 7 on ThinkPad X200 by preserving the ThinkVatnage, system recovery etc.? Do you know any step-by-step guide? My X200 came with Vista preinstalled and now I want to switch to 7.

Answer (score 1):

Thinkvantage and the System recovery is downloadable at Lenovo, e.g. see [Lenovo downloads](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=migr-61432). Keeping the partition with Vista factory software would not make sense for you.

I did this on my old X61s (Vista -> W7), straight forward, no problem, improved performance (64 bit OS instead of 32 bits). The only issue was that that model was so old that some of the  Lenovo software for that model didn't exist in a 64 bit version.

Comment: And where did you get the Win7 from?

Comment: @grigy, I bought it in a local store in Stockholm.